# Show that $\frac{\tan x}x$ with $x\in (0, \frac\pi 2)$ is a strictly increasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\dfrac{\tan(x)}{x}$,  $x\in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is a strictly increasing function.

$$f(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{x},\quad f'(x)={\frac {x\tan^2(x)-\tan (x) +x}{{x}^{2}}}.$$
How to conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{x\sec^2x-\tan x}{x^2}\ge0\iff \sec^2x\ge\frac{\tan x}x\iff\frac{2\sin2x}{x}>0\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in\left(0,\,\frac\pi2\right)$$

Comment: $\sec^2(x)\ge\frac{\tan(x)}x\iff\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\le1$

Answer (score 2):

*Another approach:*

It is enough to prove the log is increasing  (in other words, consider the logarithmic derivative).
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\tan' x}{\tan x}-\frac 1x=\frac1{\sin x\cos x}-\frac 1x=\frac2{\sin 2x}-\frac1 x=\frac{2x-\sin 2x}{x\sin 2x}>0,$$
since the denominator is positive on $(0,\pi/2)$ and  $\sin u<u$ for $u>0$ ($\sin u$ is a *convex function* on $[0,\pi]$).

Answer (score 2):

**Chatroom Question**

I answered this question in the main Mathematics chatroom:

> [How can i prove $\frac{x}{tan(x)}$ is decreasing for $x \in (0,1) $?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56047068#56047068)

using this integral
$$
\frac{x}{\tan(x)}=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2\tan^2(x)}\tag1
$$
which is decreasing for $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ since $\tan(x)$ is increasing. Therefore, its reciprocal, $\frac{\tan(x)}x$, is increasing for $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$.

---

**Motivation**

If $\frac{x}{\tan(x)}$ decreases, then so would $\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}x$. Therefore, I started with
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}x
&=\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}\tag2\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2x^2}\tag3\\
\frac{x}{\tan(x)}
&=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2\tan^2(x)}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: the integral for [arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Expression_as_definite_integrals)
$(3)$: substitute $t\mapsto tx$
$(4)$: substitute $x\mapsto\tan(x)$

Comment: Well, that is slicker than I would have thought of! :) +1

Comment: Note that we can show that $\frac{\sin(x)}x$ is decreasing on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, using the formula $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2\sin^2(x)}}$

Comment: @TedShifrin: this seemed a bit slick to me, too, so I felt I had to add the motivation so that it did not seem so much like magic. In chat, I started with $(2)$, $(3)$, and then $(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a function is $increasing$ if the firstderivative is positive on that interval.

Our derivative is: $$\dfrac{x\sec^2\left(x\right)-\tan\left(x\right)}{x^2}$$

Compute when this derivative is greater then $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac{\tan{x}}{x} \Rightarrow y'=\frac{x\sec^2{x}-\tan{x}}{x^2}.$$
For an increasing function, $y'>0$,
hence$$x\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}>\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\Rightarrow x > \sin{x}\cos{x}\Rightarrow 2x> \sin{2x},$$
in other words $\theta>\sin{\theta}$. This is true for all $\theta \in (0, +\infty)$.